# Which even numbers appear in this integer sequence?

Tags: algorithms

The first three terms of the sequence are 2, 4, 8. We call 8 the base. For every second number in the sequence that is less than the base, add the base to each of these numbers and append the sums to the sequence. In this case, every second number in the sequence that is less than the base gives us 4, which we add to 8 to give 12, and append 12 to the sequence, obtaining 2, 4, 8, 12.

Next, we double the base and append the result to the sequence, obtaining 2, 4, 8, 12, 16. Now we iterate, so with base=16, for every second number in the sequence that is less than the base, we add the base to each of these numbers, i.e. for 4 and 12, we add the base, obtaining 20 and 28. After appending those to the sequence, we obtain 2, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 28.

Again, we double the base and append the result, obtaining 2, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 28, 32. This continues indefinitely, giving rise to the integer sequence 2 4 8 12 16 20 28 32 36 44 52 64 68 76 84 96 108 128 132 140...  I  graphed the first 4000 terms against the index values 1... 4000, and it doesn't look like anything I've seen before.

My question is: given an even integer n, is there a method of determining whether n is in this sequence which is faster than computing all the terms till we reach n?  This sequence is derived from analyzing the behavior of a 5-state Turing machine. An image of the graph is at < https://twitter.com/doubledeckerpot/status/1664393554360168449/photo/1 > .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some results I got so far. Maybe you can finish this thought process to solve your problem

---

Due to the doubling action, all the powers of $2$ (excluding $1$) will be in the sequence. Since the sum action sums the base with a number smaller than itself, the sum results will be less than the double and so the sequence will be in ascending order. Hence for any even integer in the sequence that is not a power of 2, it must be a result of the sum action using the largest power of 2 smaller than it; i.e.
$$a_n = 2^{\lfloor\log_2 a_n\rfloor} + b_n, \; b_n = a_{2k} < 2^{\lfloor\log_2 a_n\rfloor} \quad  \text{for some } k < \frac{n}{2}$$

Given an integer $x$ that we want to check, we could calculate the smaller precursor by $x - 2^{\lfloor\log_2 x\rfloor}$. We could repeat this process until we get $0$ (meaning the previous value was a power of $2$). Now if all these smaller precursors in this generated sequence exist in even indices in the original sequence, then our target integer $x$ must also exist.

For this, it's useful to first determine the positions of all powers of 2. Let $p_n$ be the position of $2^n$ in the sequence. $2^{n+1}$ is appended only after appending the sum action applied on the existing even-indexed element; i.e. 2nd, 4th, ... $\left[p_n - 2 + (p_n \mod 2)\right]$th. So we have,
$$p_{n+1} = p_n + \frac{p_n - 2 + (p_n \mod 2)}{2} + 1 = \frac{3p_n + (p_n \mod 2)}{2}$$

\begin{array}
   &2^{n} & 2 & 4 & 8 & 16 & 32 & 64 & 128 \\
   p_n & 1 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 8 & 12 & 18
\end{array}

Using this formula, we can determine if a power of 2 is a valid "smaller" precursor. For example, 32 is a valid one (e.g. 96 came from 64 + 32), but 8 is not (no integer in the sequence will have come about by $2^{n} + 16$ with $n>4$)

Comment: According to your formula, the position of 256 would be $\dfrac{3 \cdot 18+0}{2}=27$, which is odd.

Comment: @ Tony Mathew I should have added: 27 is both correct and odd, as is 41, which is what your formula gives for the position of 512.

Comment: Thanks; I got confused between the value and positions of the powers of 2 when doing that last part. I have corrected it.

Comment: Many thanks. I was able to write a function is_on_list() to determine whether an input is on the list, using recursion. Unless I'm mistaken, $p_n = A061418(n)-1$, referring to the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Some partial analysis:

$a_{m_n} = 2^n \implies$

For $1 < k < m_n-m_{n-1}$,

for $m_{n-1}$: odd:
$$ a_{m_n - k} = a_{m_{n-1}} + a_{m_{n-1}-2k+1}$$
$$m_n = m_{n-1} + \frac{m_{n-1}-1}{2}+1 = 1.5 \times m_{n-1} +0.5$$

Hence,
$$ a_{m_n - k} = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_{m_{q_i}} = \sum_{i = 1}^n 2^{q_i}$$
$$q_{i+1} = \min \{\ell: m_{\ell} \geq m_{q_{i}-1}-k_{i+1}\}$$
$$q_1 = n-1.$$
$$q_0 = n-1$$
for $i$ odd,
$$ k_{i+1} = 2(m_{q_{i}} - (m_{q_{i-1}-1} - k_{i}))-1$$

$$k_1 = k$$
for $i$ even,
$$ k_{i+1} = 2(m_{q_{i}} - (m_{q_{i-1}-1} - k_{i}))$$

for $m_{n-1}$: even:

$$ a_{m_n - k} = a_{m_{n-1}} + a_{m_{n-1}-2k}$$
$$m_n = m_{n-1} + \frac{m_{n-1}-2}{2}+1 = 1.5 \times m_{n-1}$$

Hence,
$$ a_{m_n - k} = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_{m_{q_i}} = \sum_{i = 1}^n 2^{q_i}$$
$$q_{i+1} = \min \{\ell: m_{\ell} \geq m_{q_{i}-1}-k_{i+1}\}$$
$$q_1 = n-1.$$
$$q_0 = n-1$$
for $i$ even,
$$ k_{i+1} = 2(m_{q_{i}} - (m_{q_{i-1}-1} - k_{i}))-1$$

for $i$ odd,
$$ k_{i+1} = 2(m_{q_{i}} - (m_{q_{i-1}-1} - k_{i}))$$
$$k_1 = k$$

Hope the above helps.